Why do they put salt in a "saline" intravenous infusion?
Why do they put 0.9 mg/ml salt (NaCl, sodium chloride) into intravenous infusions?
(Especially in emergency situations)
The common assertion I find is "it helps keeping veins open", but neither do I understand the chemical principle there, nor am I really satisfied with this as the sole reason (especially regarding it emergency IVs).
So why salt, and not some state-of-the-art combination of ~10 hormones?

Does it have to do with osmosis? (If there wass les/no salt in there, would the 'water' reach its destination or seep away too early in some tissues/limbs?)
Does it prophylactically provide the body with much-needed isotones? (As in: 'people do not eat enough salt' or 'most cardio-vascular problems are a result of xxx deficiency'?)

Update
The infos I found so far are:

0.9 mg/ml makes the infusion isotonic (same osmolarity as blood)
sodium is also used for muscle contraction, so a possible lack thereof might be alleviated
the chloride may help maintaining acid-base balance (extracellular pH levels)

So do you guys know of any further advantages? Something more specific to nutrition or the circulatory system?

Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For reasons mentioned in this post and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. See this list of helpful resources. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Specifically, you mentioned osmosis, and that's a good place to start. I plugged your question into google and the first hits answered it.

The first thing I did was googling it, but it didn't get me anywhere near, so I asked here. So if you'd be so kind as to drop me a link maybe...?

I asked google, Why is salt added to iv fluids? This is the response. Ignore the AI overview. Take a look at the subsequent answers.

If you administer only fluid without electrolytes, the fluid will shift into the intracellular space. This is similar to infusing 5% dextrose; the dextrose is rapidly metabolized, leaving free water to enter the cells. This can cause cellular swelling and lead to edema, which is particularly harmful to neurons.
